# Bootstrap3 navbar issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the height of the bootstrap navbar. But I only want to change it for desktop screens. I do not want to change it for any screens below 700 px. Please advice where to change and what to change.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media(min-width: 700px) {
  .navbar{
     min-height: XXpx;
  }
}
```

Put this is a custom CSS file. Replace 'XX' with whatever height you desire.

Comment: thank you.
May I know how I vertical align the navbar when it is in a menu. I know it doing in standard css. But with bootstrap, it would just not happen.

Comment: .nav-main .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: XXpx; 
    padding-bottom: XXpx; 
}